# Center a chart inside of bootstrap's carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am using `highcharts` to make a chart then render it inside a `div` in my carousel, but they seem to be offset to the left. How can I center each div (inline)?

**My carousel example**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
            <div id ="chartId"></div>
                             //chart is appended here
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                 </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**Tried:**

1. Adding `style="width:100%"` to chart's div - did not work
2. Adding `style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;"` which seems to work but won't this change depending on the monitor?

Comment: have you tried the absolute positioning trick? change the parent div (or wrap one more time) to `position:relative` then change the chart to `position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0` (or something to that effect, basically just pulling the edges out). this may interfere with the bootstrap styles though, so may not work.

Comment: @DarrenKopp I have not tried that yet, I will try it and edit my post

Comment: Another thing you can try is setting margin-right:50%, margin-left:50%

Comment: @DarrenKopp I tried that and the chart no longer renders.

Answer (score 1):

setting `margin: 0 auto` will always center the chart, regardless of the monitor

Comment: But this does not work unless I set the width of the div. Couldn't that cause an odd looking chart depending on the monitor?

Comment: why would it look odd? having `width: 800px`, the width will always be 800px, regardless of the monitor.

Comment: precisely, which on larger monitors will not be 'as centered' as smaller and such.